# Overridden CSS Styles with Background Images

Tags: css

There are two CSS files referenced on the same page: A generic.css file and a custom.css file. The generic file has default styles in it that are overridden by the custom.css file for the same elements. This allows users of the site to customize or "skin" their pages without needing to recreate the entire generic.css file. Only a few styles would be overridden.

My question is the following: If the generic.css file has a style for an element with a background image and that same style is overridden in the custom.css with a different background image, is the first image ever downloaded by the browser?

Also, I want to find out if this is bad practice - customizing or "skinning" a generic CSS file with another custom CSS file to override a few styles, including specifying different background images.

Comment: check w/ httpfox for activity

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks, I will. However, that would only cover Firefox. My question is what should be the expected behavior of a browser based on standards (if this part is covered). Also if this is bad practice or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not totally definitive, [this site](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/a-look-at-how-browsers-download-and-render-css-background-images/) ran some tests regarding this. The significant statement from that site that is related to your question is:

> CSS images are kicked off not in the order in which they appear in the
>   CSS but in the order in which they’re called in the HTML. I’m not sure
>   of the precise moment when the download is initiated, but my guess is
>   that it happens just after the CSS rules have been matched, when the
>   property values are assigned to the DOM elements.

This at least tentatively confirms what I thought I remembered in the back of my mind reading on this a few years back, namely, that background images which are not ever displayed (as in the generic.css images being overridden by the custom.css images) are not ever downloaded.

Further confirmation of this would be the typical image preloader script that used to be so common prior to sprite images (and is still found in certain uses). It was designed to download images that would be used on `:hover` in css, because without it, the image would not load until the first hover was initiated, and this caused an unsightly delay. So that, also, argues for the fact that unless actually displayed (or preloaded), the background images themselves are never loaded.

I don't think there are generally any issues with "skinning," unless you are essentially overwriting most or all of the generic.css with custom.css, then one could argue, why load the generic at all. But as you said, normally there are just a few styles overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I think i answered **NO** and **NO BAD PRACTICE**. Because when the css file readable / executable by the browser, the browser will make comparisons to find the same value or the difference between css file and then combine them.

Easy example:

**css1.css** on file there is a line:

```
.test {display: block; width: 100%; height: 600px; background: #991100 url("image1.jpg") center top; border: 1px solid red;}
```

then the **css2.css** there is also the line:

```
.test {background: #991100 url("image2.jpg") no-repeat center center;}
```

the result of a combination that will be executed and run by the browser are:

```
.test {display: block; width: 100%; height: 600px; background: url("image2.jpg") no-repeat center center # 991100; border: 1px solid red}
```

where the "background: # 991100 url("image1.jpg") center top;" read but not called / executed by the browser.

Far as I know the value of the file **css1.css** be stacked by the value of the **css2.css**. What if there a **css3.css** file? then the file css3.css will also stacking on the combination of css1.css and css2.css.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. Both you and ScottS provided very good answers. ScottS answered first. +1 to you for the helpful explanation.